# Stacked IF formulas with Match doesn't produce right condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match

I have written this to serve my purposes. The only part that doesn't work is the condition "if a cell is in a list and if the cell isn't empty `AND` isn't in the list, then return "New Index"". However for this condition it returns the #N/A error. Would anyone be able to see where my syntax is incorrect or perhaps my whole approach is incorrect!:

```
=IF(LEN(Data!E6)>0,IF(MATCH(Data!E6,'A L'!$K:$K,0)>0,"--","NEW INDEX"),"")
```

been baffled for a while so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MATCH() will return a number or an error so change it to:

```
ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data!E6,'A L'!$K:$K,0))
```

So your whole formula is:

```
=IF(LEN(Data!E6)>0,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data!E6,'A L'!$K:$K,0)),"--","NEW INDEX"),"")
```

Comment: ooooooooohhhhhh!!! :D Appropriate formatting is the bane of my excel life once again!.~Thanks for the help Scott!